# z-index of geoJSONs and imageOverlays in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

There have been several Github issues raised regarding Leaflet z-indexing of layers, and I'm still not clear where things stand. I think my question is quite simple:

Is it possible to set *any* stacking order of a mixture of `geoJSON` and `imageOverlay` layers? If so, how, and can it be done in 0.7.7, or only in 1.0.0-beta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know of to arbitrarily manipulate layer z-indexing relies on the pane features introduced in 1.0.0-beta, specifically the `map.createPane` and `map.getPane` methods combined with the ability to set a `pane` option for each layer.

You start by creating new panes for each of your layers to occupy:

```
map.createPane('newPane1');
map.createPane('newPane2');
map.createPane('newPane3');
[etc...]
```

You can then assign your layers to whichever pane you want by setting `pane: 'newPane1'` (or `pane: 'newPane2'` etc.) in the layer options.

To reorder the panes (and the layers within them), you can use the `getPane` method like so:

```
map.getPane('newPane1').style.zIndex = 402;
map.getPane('newPane2').style.zIndex = 399;
map.getPane('newPane3').style.zIndex = 401;
[etc...]
```

One important thing to know is that while the [documentation for 1.0b](http://mourner.github.io/Leaflet/reference.html#map-panes) still describes the `zIndex` values as being 2 for tiles, 4 for overlays etc., these values have actually been multiplied by 100 in the new beta, so whenever you create a new pane, it gets a `zIndex` of 400 by default. The rendering order of different panes with the same `zIndex` appears to be determined by the order in which they were created (panes created later are on top of those created earlier).

Here's a somewhat overly-complicated example fiddle, with sliders to adjust the z-indices of a few different layers:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/4gmqf0ug/

Comment: Many thanks for all the details. I'll wait for 1.0.0 full release to try to use this technique.

Comment: This SO answer linked to here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36603252/4355695 . The feature seems fully rolled out circa 2021. Another sample code: http://www.java2s.com/example/javascript/leaflet/set-the-zindex-layer-order-for-geojson-layers.html