# Display Leaflet WMS Layers from same source on different panes

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wms, layers

I am using the [Leaflet WMS](https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms) plugin to add in layers to my map via a WMS.

I have the following code below that adds all of the layers using the same source but as separate layers.

However, I want to set each of the layers to its own pane so that when I add/remove them to/from the map they appear in the correct order as defined by the list of panes, rather than the order they were added to the map as currently happens without the panes.

```
var source = L.WMS.source("http://IP ADDRESS:PORT/geoserver/wms", {
format: 'image/png',
transparent: true,
tiled: true,
opacity: 0.6,
minZoom: 12,
tileSize: 512,
attribution: "Attribution Here"
});
var layer1 = source.getLayer("WORKSPACE:layer_1");
var layer2 = source.getLayer("WORKSPACE:layer_2");
var layer3 = source.getLayer("WORKSPACE:layer_3");
var layer4 = source.getLayer("WORKSPACE:layer_4");
```

Comment: [This answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178873/56906) may describe the solution you're looking for. Note that if you don't intend to reorder the panes later, you may not even need to explicitly set the z-index; simply creating the panes in the order you want them to appear (from lowest to highest) and setting the `pane` option for each layer should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I've used this method explained in your answer before successfully, just struggling in this case to work out where I would assign the layer to the pane? without assigning the entire `source` to one pane?

Comment: Ah yes, that is a problem. I somehow had it in my head that you could set the pane after creating the layer, using `layer1.options.pane = 'myPaneName` or the like. That is not the case, but you can create a pane called `layerPane1` and use `map.getPane('layerPane1').appendChild(layer1.getContainer());` to attach the layer to the pane even after you've created it. Then create panes for the other layers and follow the same method. I'll write up an answer later on why this works, but this is basically the same workaround that's used to change the zIndex of a tile layer in Leaflet 0.7

Comment: My apologies. The`wms.Layer` class doesn't include a `.getContainer()` method, so the `.appendChild` trick doesn't work here either. It looks like the only way around this problem is to either modify the leaflet.wms code or find another plugin.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this further @nathansnider, might have to look at the leaflet.wms code if there doesn't seem to be a workaround. Any suggestion on where to start with this?

Comment: My suggestion would be to start with [Leaflet's `GridLayer` code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js), specifically the internal [`_initContainer` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js#L197). Incorporating `_initContainer` and `getContainer` into [the `wms.Layer` class](https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms/blob/gh-pages/leaflet.wms.js#L219) should at least allow for the `.appendChild` workaround.

Comment: It's probably even possible to assign layers to panes at the time they are created if you modify [getLayer](https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms/blob/gh-pages/leaflet.wms.js#L82) to accept options (and pass them on to wms.Layer).